# Content is blurr in Webview - IPHONE X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

[image: Blurr content]

I have a Webview in my app, which works fine till Iphone 8. In Iphone X, content is very blurr in the Webview, font is not crisp and pictures are pixeled. Any ideas how this can be fixed (I am already using safe area in storyboard).Below is the code for my Webview

```
    //Example URL
    let url = URL(string: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en")
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)



    self.webView.addSubview(self.Activity)
    self.Activity.startAnimating()
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.Activity.hidesWhenStopped = true

    webViewContainer.addSubview(webView!)
```

Comment: Is the screenshot from an actual device, or the simulator?

Comment: Simulater, but on the actual device I have the same issue. There is no difference.